# Access an array sent from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, json, arrays

So I am trying to get sent an array of json objects from php file to js.

The method that I am using seems to be working since I used console.log to print the object (array) I am getting and I got what I really sent in the following format

```
(
[0] => {"id":"1","name":"mmdftd","phone":"5785","year":"2013","app_status":"in_progress"}
[1] => {"id":"2","name":"shsoshsdo","phone":"58","year":"2013","app_status":"in_progress"}
)
```

However I am facing an issue reading this array

I tried different ways to access it as following

First Way: .each function

```
$(data).each(function() {
        console.log("This| " + this);
    console.log("ID| " + val.id);
    console.log("Name| " + val.name);
    console.log("Phone| " + val.phone);
    console.log("Year| " + val.year);
    console.log("APP Status| " + val.app_status);
}
```

However this results in the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Array
```

Second way: Using while loog
I am looping using this condition

```
while(data[i] != null)
```

However this results in an infinite loop

Any recommendation on which is the best practice to access such array ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use data = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 1):

On PHP:

```
$data = array(
     [0] => array("id"=>"1","name"=>"mmdftd","phone"=>"5785","year"=>"2013","app_status"=>"in_progress"),
     [1] => array("id"=>"2","name"=>"shsoshsdo","phone"=>"58","year"=>"2013","app_status"=>"in_progress")
)

echo json_encode($data);
```

On JavaScript:

Let's assume you got the data by an ajax request.

```
 $.get('url-to-php-file.php', function(data) {
         data = JSON.parse(data);
         // Here you can do whatever you want with the data
    });
```

Comment: 1. one should not use `POST` to retrieve data; 2. jQuery is smart enough to recognize JSON if headers are properly set, so no need to parse.

Comment: 1. Agree. 2. I would say it's good practice to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Nice but for some reason that was like have the solution I had to parse as you said then like a second layer of parsing
1- var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
2- val = jQuery.parseJSON(obj);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    var obj = JSON.parse(value);
    $.each(obj, function(key2, value2){
    console.log(key2 + ' - ' + value2);
    });
});
```